Getting stuck in trying to web scrape PrizePicks CS2 props
I am trying to web scrape CS2 props from Prizepicks, but it's getting stuck at one piece of code and I don't know how to fix this part. I tried to use the api thing but it's not working too well for me so I'm trying to pull it from app.prizepicks instead. Any advice would be greatly appreciated because I genuinely don't know what else to do.
Here's the code below:
from path import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

############################################################################

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()  # Open the window in full screen mode

############################################################################

# Scraping PrizePicks
driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/")
time.sleep(5)

# Waiting and closes popup
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "close")))
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/button").click()
time.sleep(3)

# Creating tables for players
ppPlayers = []

# It will click CS2 tab, if you want to scrape a different sport, change 'CS2' to the sport of your liking. 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='name'][normalize-space()='CS2']").click()
time.sleep(3)

# Waits until stat container element is viewable
stat_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "stat-container")))

# Finding all the stat elements within the stat-container. (In this case, it's Map 1-2 Kills, Headshots, etc.)
categories = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='button'][normalize-space()='MAPS 1-2 Headshots']").click()
projectionsPP = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".projection")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
element_wait = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(projectionsPP))

# Creating tables for players
ppPlayers = []



############################################################################

# Data Scraping Automation begins here

for projection in projectionsPP:

    names = projection.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="name"]').text
    value = projection.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="presale-score"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    proptype = projection.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "text").get_attribute('innerHTML')

    players = {
            'Name': names,
            'Value': value,
            'Prop': proptype.replace("<wbr>", "")
        }

    ppPlayers.append(players)

dfProps = pd.DataFrame(ppPlayers)
dfProps.to_csv('CS2 Props.csv')

print("PrizePicks Props Offered: ", '\n')
print(dfProps)
print('\n')

driver.quit()

I want it to pull the prop information from the CS2 tab and print to an excel sheet, but once I run the debugger it'll go to the CS2 tab and get stuck at this specific part. It ends up timing out every time and no matter how much I increase the time, it just gets stuck right there.
projectionsPP = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".projection")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
element_wait = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(projectionsPP))

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I don't really know how to use Stack Overflow efficiently just yet so please give me grace if I messed something basic up, thank you!

If it is timing up no matter how much time you put, then you must not be reading the element correctly. Try using different path to access the element.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

TLDR; Do NOT try and scrape the HTML directly. Call the backend API instead which will give you the raw JSON of the projections instead.
driver.get("https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=${leagueId}&per_page=250&single_stat=true&game_mode=pickem")

When doing that, make sure you handle the Cloudflare issues to avoid getting 403 responses.
How to handle Cloudflare issues
A couple things to note when NOT using Selenium:

IP address matters - residential or ISP ip's usually work
HTTP/2.0 - PrizePicks blocks standard python http client requests because they default to using HTTP/1.0
Include all of the headers used when loading the page in your browser

When using Selenium:

The only thing that matters is IP address
And ensuring you use the stealth configuration
Use the backend endpoint (api.prizepicks.com) instead of the frontend URL (app.prizepicks.com) to get the data directly instead of scraping the HTML

Use api.prizepicks instead of app.prizepicks
Try calling the API directly (instead of app.prizepicks.com) using this endpoint. (remember headers, http2.0, and ensure your IP address if from your home or another residential IP)
driver.get("https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=${leagueId}&per_page=250&single_stat=true&game_mode=pickem")

Replace leagueId with the ID you care about e.g. CSGO is 124
Here's an example CURL (defaults to HTTP2.0) that should return the projections for NBA in JSON:
curl 'https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=7&per_page=250&single_stat=true&game_mode=pickem' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Referer: https://app.prizepicks.com/' \
  -H 'X-Device-ID: 1a9d6304-65f3-4304-8523-ccf458d3c0c4' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"'

Use a Data provider instead
There are a couple of APIs that provide lines from different DFS books so that you don't need to setup all of the infrastructure to scrape these books.

https://www.dailyfantasyapi.io (Recommended) - they have major DFS books like PrizePicks, Underdog, ParlayPlay, etc with all of the major sports leagues. They also score and grade the lines which you won't get directly from the site and you'd have to build infra around that
https://www.sportsdata.io - they sell lines to all books and PrizePicks is one of the books they sell. They more focus on traditional books, not as much DFS books


Instead of sending request to https://api.prizepicks.com you should send the request to https://partner-api.prizepicks.com

I recommend to use proper formatting to help with telling a solution here from a link to a solution (which can be misread and get your post flagged). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
